# Algorithm to compute Matrix Sign Rank?

Tags: algorithms, approximation-algorithms, computation

The (generalised) sign-rank of a (generalised) sign pattern $S\in \{+,-,0\}^{n\times m}$
is the minimum rank of all matrices with the same sign pattern, i.e.
$$
\min\left\{\operatorname{rank}(M)\ :\ M\in \mathbf{R}^{n\times m} \text{ and } \operatorname{sign}(M_{i,j}) = S_{i,j}\text{ for all }i,j\right\}
$$

This problem is known to be as hard as the existential theory of reals. Has there been any advances in computing this value, either exactly, or an approximation algorithm, or even a heuristic that is good in practice?

Comment: See the CSTheory question, '[Approximating the sign rank of a matrix](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/178/337)." The accepted answer says, "I believe this is an open question." And another answer there refers to recent work by Alon, Moran, and Yehudayoff ([arXiv link](https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.07648).)

Comment: @ShantBoodaghians what do you mean by 'as hard as the existential theory of reals'?

Answer (score 1):

Given positive integers $m$ and $n$, and sets $\mathcal P, \mathcal Z, \mathcal N$ that **partition** the set

$$\{1, 2, \dots, m\} \times \{1, 2, \dots, n\}$$

and indicate which entries of the matrix are *positive*, *zero* or *negative*, respectively, we have the following constrained rank-minimization problem

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \mbox{rank} (\mathrm X)\\ \text{subject to} & \mathrm X_{ij} > 0 \quad \forall (i,j) \in \mathcal P\\ & \mathrm X_{ij} = 0 \quad \forall (i,j) \in \mathcal Z\\ & \mathrm X_{ij} < 0 \quad \forall (i,j) \in \mathcal N\end{array}$$

which is *non-convex*, unfortunately. However, a **convex relaxation** of the rank-minimization problem is to minimize the **nuclear norm** of $\mathrm X$, which is denoted by $\| \mathrm X \|_*$. We introduce $0 < \epsilon \ll 1$ so that we have *non-strict* inequalities. Hence,

$$\boxed{\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \| \mathrm X \|_*\\ \text{subject to} & \mathrm X_{ij} \geq \epsilon \quad \forall (i,j) \in \mathcal P\\ & \mathrm X_{ij} = 0 \quad \forall (i,j) \in \mathcal Z\\ & \mathrm X_{ij} \leq -\epsilon \,\,\, \forall (i,j) \in \mathcal N\end{array}}$$

The $\| \cdot \|_*$-minimization problem can be formulated as a **semidefinite program** (SDP) [MG14] in matrices $\mathrm X \in \mathbb R^{m \times n}$, $\mathrm W_1 \in \mathbb R^{m \times m}$ and $\mathrm W_2 \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}$

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \frac 12 \mbox{tr} (\mathrm W_1) + \frac 12 \mbox{tr} (\mathrm W_2)\\ \text{subject to} & \begin{bmatrix} \mathrm W_1 & \mathrm X\\ \mathrm X^{\top} & \mathrm W_2\end{bmatrix} \succeq \mathrm O_{m+n}\\ & \mathrm X_{ij} \geq \epsilon \quad \forall (i,j) \in \mathcal P\\ & \mathrm X_{ij} = 0 \quad \forall (i,j) \in \mathcal Z\\ & \mathrm X_{ij} \leq -\epsilon \,\,\, \forall (i,j) \in \mathcal N\end{array}$$

---

[MG14] Michael Grant, [Derivative of the nuclear norm with respect to its argument](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/704271), Mathematics Stack Exchange, April 2014.

Comment: Doesn't the nuclear norm scale? So your first problem always has minimum $0$, and the second problem has a minimum that scales linearly with $\epsilon$. It is nonobvious whether the bound in your second problem with $\epsilon=1$ has any implication for the rank minimization problem.

Comment: @WillSawin If the nuclear norm is $0$, then the sum of the singular values is zero, which implies that $\rm X = O$. This $\rm X$ does not satisfy the strict inequalities, though. Am I misunderstanding your point?

Comment: rather I should say that the infimum is zero and the minimum is undefined. Of course $0$ cannot be attained but norms arbitrarily close to it can.

Comment: @WillSawin You are absolutely correct. I have edited my answer. Thanks for bringing the error to my attention.